# UTF-8 chars broken only in Django template

Tags: python, django, utf-8, django-templates

I'm currently working on a reporting app (written using Django) for our librarians in order to solve some issues we have with certain labs (I work in a university). To achieve so, I've created a page listing all problematic labs. I was testing adding annotation, which works perfectly. Except for UTF8 chars. And I don't know (yet) what part of the process fails.

PROBLEM : **è** char is printed as **Ã¨** in the HTML page.

Here is my personal 'traceback' :

1. I am connected to my test server via SSH using Terminal.app (which is in UTF-8)
2. The server's `LANG` is `en_US.UTF-8`
3. I added the annotation ( `annotation.text = u'2ème commentaire'` ) via `python manage.py shell_plus` which launches ipython
4. I tried adding `DEFAULT_CHARSET="utf-8"` in my settings, with no change.
5. I checked MySQL's config : `character_set_database` is `utf8`. A `SELECT` shows the right text.
6. In my views.py, I just get the annotations from DB and sort them. Then I call `direct_to_template` with a dict containing the data.
7. In my template, the HTML page charset is set with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` and I print the annotations with `{{ annotation.text|escape }}`.

The problem seems to appear at step 5-6 but I don't know how to catch it and — obviously — how to correct it. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

PS: I can provide you more code if you want but it's more likely to confuse you (since the DB structure is kind of weird I think).

---

**ANSWER**
(Since I have less than 10 rep, I can't answer to myself for now, so I post the answer below.)

I found the answer, finally !

```
In [13]: annotation.text
Out[13]: u'2\xc3\xa8me commentaire'

In [14]: annotation.text = '2ème commentaire'
In [15]: annotation.save()
In [16]: annotation.text
Out[16]: '2\xc3\xa8me commentaire'
```

Apparently the 'u' indicating the string is in UTF-8 was an 'overkill'. There are two ways to encode the same char in UTF-8 (if I correctly understood what I read):

```
In [37]: print('\xc3\xa8').decode('utf8')
è

In [38]: print(u'\xe8')
è

In [39]: print(u'\xc3\xa8')
Ã¨
```

I just chose a mix of the two, and... well, that was wrong.

Thanks for the answers anyway !

Comment: What encoding is checked in the browser when you view `tools->encoding`

Comment: Firefox tells me UTF-8 is the page encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your template (the HTML file itself) encoded in UTF-8 ?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't change a thing. I chose your answer as accepted answer to signify others an answer has been found, which is true, even if it's not yours. Anyway, thanks for the response !